# AngularJS: Getting KeyValuePairs in Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently writing an AngularJS directive that allows me to set certain classes when I hover on a specific element.

Therefore, I've created the following directive:

```
OfficeUIModule.directive('toggleStyleAttributeOnHover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            var toggleStyleAttributes =     attributes['toggleStyleAttributeOnHover'];

            element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                console.log(toggleStyleAttributes);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

When I create my HTML, I do pass an attribute to my element, allowing this directive to be executed.

This looks like the following:

```
data-toggle-style-attribute-on-hover="{'color': {{contextualGroup.GroupTextColor}}}"
```

When I execute my page right now, in the console window of my browser, I do see the following output: `{'color': #cf5c0a}`

So, this looks quite good, but now I need to parse this object so that I can add a style atribute saying that the color should be #cf5c0a

Off course, this directive might accept several parameters, meaning that they should all be taken into account.

I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Is the colour set in a controller?

Comment: The color is defined in a Json, and I need a way to change the color when I hover on the element.

Comment: you could just set the colour as the attribute value `data-toggle-style-attribute-on-hover="{{contextualGroup.GroupTextColor}}"`

Comment: I can, but I don't like that because than my directive is a bit wrong. I would like to be able to pass various arguments to this directive (might be usefull in the future).

Comment: You might want to use bindings for this instead of attributes

Comment: That does sound like magic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case as you're passing in a key-value paired object you could simply call `JSON.parse` and then take the color property.

```
JSON.parse(toggleStyleAttributes).color
```

If you're referring to the way the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive works, it uses `scope.$eval` under the hood. You could make use of that but in order to make that work you'd need to remove the curly braces out of the expression, like:

```
data-toggle-style-attribute-on-hover="{'color':contextualGroup.GroupTextColor}"
```

You should then be able to access the color property, much like in the case if you'd used JSON.parse.

Comment: This will not work as the output I'm giving is not a valid JSon string. I can adapt this, but default AngularJS directives works the same way, so I would like to keep consistent.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for now but might change if I find another solution.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken. You could fix this by updating your expression to `"{'color': '{{contextualGroup.GroupTextColor}} }'"` if that suits your needs? If you're referring to the `ngClass` directive, it's not entirely the same as the equivalent syntax would be `"{'color': contextualGroup.GroupTextColor}"`.

Comment: And can you explain perhaps on how that one is working?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

To parse string to object, i think you should format string like that:

```
{"color": "#cf5c0a"}
```

Put key and value into "".

Answer (score 0):

Using 2-way bindings instead of attributes

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('toggleStyleAttributeOnHover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            config: '=toggleStyleAttributeOnHover'
        },
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                element.css('color', scope.config.color);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I don't know what style attributes will be passed in.